# Update Image in database using EF & MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

MY upload and displaying of image in database works,however I keep getting an error when I try to update image. It gives an error of : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Below is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StoreID,CustomerID,StoreName,StoreUID,StoreNumber,StoreLogo,StoreLogoPath,StoreAddress,StoreCity,StoreRegion,StoreCountry")] Store store, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName);

                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                store.StoreLogoPath = Request.Form["StoreLogoPath"];
                store.StoreLogo = ImageName;

                db.Stores.Add(store);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }


        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", store.CustomerID);

        return View(store);
    }


 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Store store = db.Stores.Find(id);
        if (store == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", store.CustomerID);
        return View(store);
    }

    // POST: Stores/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StoreID,CustomerID,StoreName,StoreUID,StoreNumber,StoreLogo,StoreLogoPath,StoreAddress,StoreCity,StoreRegion,StoreCountry")] Store store, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName);

            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            store.StoreLogoPath = Request.Form["StoreLogoPath"];
            store.StoreLogo = ImageName;
            db.Entry(store).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", store.CustomerID);
        return View(store);
    }
```

The edit View

```html
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Store Logo</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreLogo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
}
```

Comment: **Where** do you get that error?

Comment: At this line in the edit code - string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

Comment: And what is the value of `FileName`?

Comment: Its just retrieves the actual file name of the image uploaded

Comment: Please debug and find out the specific value that is saved in `FileName`. I suppose, that `file` is not set correctly

Comment: Managed to get rid of the error by adding :  if (file != null)... it still does not update the image though

Comment: Nevermind, managed to fix it. Just added this to the view: @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Stores", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: You're just missing `FormMethod.Post` in `BeginForm` there. If this parameter not supplied the request may treated as GET & hitting wrong controller action method.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto , Yes realised I was missing that. Thanks :)